# Create a new list with values from HashMap from existing list

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I want to create a new List from Map from existing list.

I got an ArrayList as below structure;

```
ArrayList
         0 = {LinkedHashMap}
                   0 = {LinkedHashMapEntry} "name" --> "value"
                   1 = {LinkedHashMapEntry} "surname" --> "value"
         1 = {LinkedHashMap}
                   0 = {LinkedHashMapEntry} "name" --> "value"
                   1 = {LinkedHashMapEntry} "surname" --> "value"
         ....
```

What I want to do is get all name values as a new list.

```
List<String> allNames = ....
```

Is there any way to get this list with using Java Stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
List<String> allNames =
    list.stream() // this creates a Stream<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>
        .map(m->m.get("name")) // this maps the original Stream to a Stream<String>
                               // where each Map of the original Stream in mapped to the
                               // value of the "name" key in that Map
        .filter(Objects::nonNull) // this filters out any null values
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // this collects the elements
                                       // of the Stream to a List
```

Comment: Can you please explain this? I was trying something similar on my IDE but didn't get this .map(m-> m.get("name")) thing. As the list is of Map, won't it pass a map as "m" ?

Comment: @BilboBaggins see edit. Yes, `m`'s type is `Map` (or `LinkedHashMap`, depending on how you declared the input `List`)

Comment: A side note : `filter(Objects::nonNull)` is not a requirement.

Comment: @Eran Thank you :)

Comment: @davidxxx It made sense to me to avoid having `null`s in the output `List`.